# Property missing in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have setup my `localhost` to new PC. After import the database to `phpmyadmin`, I run `laravel` and open the page. However, I got this error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\inventoryApp\resources\views\Item\edit.blade.php)

On the other page, I got this error:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\inventoryApp\resources\views\Item\show.blade.php)

My `view` code looks like:

```html
    <table id="sale-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Seller</th>
                <th>Item ID</th>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Total Sale</th>
                <th>Detail</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($sales as $sale)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $sale->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->item_id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->item->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->quantity }}</td>
                    <td>RM {{ $sale->price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $sale->created_at }}</td>
                    @if(Auth::user()->type=='admin'||Auth::user()->type=='super_admin')
                        <td class="center">
                            <a href="{{ route('Sale.edit', ['id'=>$sale->id ]) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm custom"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> EDIT</a>
                        </td> 
                        <td class="center">
                            <form action="{{ route('Sale.destroy', ['id'=>$sale->id ]) }}" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('Delete sale {{ $sale->name }} permanently?')" >
                                <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> DELETE</button>
                            </form>
                        </td> 
                    @else
                        <td class="center">
                            <b><p>Only for admin</p></b>   
                        </td>
                        <td class="center">
                            <b><p>Only for admin</p></b>   
                        </td>
                    @endif
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**My controller is:**

```php
    class SalesController extends Controller
    {

        public function index()
        {
            $sales=Sale::all();
            return view('Sale.index')->with('sales',$sales);
        }

        public function create()
        {
            $items=Item::all();
            return view('Sale.create')->with('items',$items);;
        }

        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'item_id'=>'required|integer',
                //'price'=>'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
                'quantity'=>'required|integer',
            ]);

            $item=Item::FindOrFail($request->item_id);
            $item->quantity -= ($request->quantity);

            $sale=new Sale;
            $sale->seller_id=$request->get('seller_id');
            $sale->item_id=$item->id;
            $sale->price=$item->selling_price * $request->input('quantity');
            $sale->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
            $sale->save();
            $item->save();

            return redirect('/Sale')->with('success','Sale added');
        }

        public function edit($id)
        {
            $sales=Sale::find($id);
            return view('Sale.edit')->with('sales',$sales);
        }

        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                //'price'=>'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
                'quantity'=>'required|integer',
            ]);

            $sale=Sale::find($id);
            $item=Item::FindOrFail($sale->item_id);
            $item->quantity = $item->quantity + $sale->quantity - $request->quantity;
            $sale->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
            $sale->price=$item->selling_price * $request->input('quantity');

            $item->save();
            $sale->save();

            return redirect('/Sale')->with('success','Sale updated');
        }

        public function destroy($id)
        {
            $sale = Sale::find($id);
            $sale->delete();
            return redirect('/Sale')->with('success','Sale Removed');
        }
    }
```

When I try to add a new item, it works well. But I cannot use the imported one.

Comment: share your controller and view code

Comment: the error tells you the line number where it is caused ... what is the problem that you can't seem to figure out?

Comment: When I add new item to the database, the item can be edit, view and delete. However, if I use the item that I import from sql file to the database, I cannot edit, view and delete that specific item.

Comment: have you `id` column or `sale_id` in table ...?

Comment: Yes I have it in my sale database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have id column in your sale table.

and you have create the relationship with your user model and item model in your migration file and sale model.

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class); // assuming you have named the model "Item" for your item table. 
    }
```

Comment: Yes I have it. Do I need to configure anything if I import any item into the database?

Comment: check the database tables if it has relationship build up correctly.